# how to pass array value from model to jquery datepicker?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am trying to highlight days on the calendar. The highlighted days are from the view model(IEnumerable type). My code is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var datesArray = new Array();
   for (var item in Model) { 
     datesArray[datesArray.length] = "<%= item.PerformanceDate.Day %>";
   }
  $(document).ready(function()  {

   // Datepicker
   $('.datepicker').datepicker({
     inline: true,
     beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        var theday = date.getDate();
        if ($.inArray(theday, datesArray) <0) return [true, ""];
           return [true, "specialDate"];
        }

   });
});
```

Please let me know whats wrong with my code...

Thanks a Lot!!
Anusha

Comment: How did you know my name is Jon?

Comment: New array's in JS should be created using var datesArray = [];

Comment: I just saw your name in some other thread. You asked if there is a way to show events based on data from database on the datepicker. I am trying to do the same. Initially i want to highlight days that have events. I have the list of days in my model. But, i am getting an error saying that item does not exist

Answer (score 0):

This part looks wrong:

```
 if ($.inArray(theday, datesArray) <0) return [true, ""];
           return [true, "specialDate"];
        }
```

You should probably use {} when using an if statement instead of relying on the single line if statement check.  Also, what error are you getting back?  As for the code, I might suggest this instead:

```
 beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        var theday = date.getDate();
        if ($.inArray(theday, datesArray) <0) {
           return [true, ""];
        }
        return [true, "specialDate"];
 }
```

Comment: The if part works fine...it says item does not exist in the context. I am trying to access the Model properties to get an array of dates